# Spring custom oauth2 response data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm a new of java spring, I want to custom oauth2 response data to add my user data but its hard for me and my data response like this

```
{
  "access_token": "4024beac-bc3d-463c-8225-4183e7d8a057",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "refresh_token": "5d748d08-ca89-4de2-a2ac-0de2043ee53e",
   "expires_in": 298,
   "scope": "read write"
}
```

I want like this

```
{
"access_token": "4024beac-bc3d-463c-8225-4183e7d8a057",
"token_type": "bearer",
"refresh_token": "5d748d08-ca89-4de2-a2ac-0de2043ee53e",
"expires_in": 298,
"scope": "read write",
"myUserData": {"id" : 1,"firstName": "Hiku","lastname": "Saing"}
}
```

And Here is my code 3 files config

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("admin").secret(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("123"))
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(5 * 60)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(10 * 60);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        endpoints.pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/login/**");
    }
}

public class ResourceServiceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/login/**", "/register").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceLoginImp userService;
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();

    }
    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Knowing that you can get those information from the `Authentication` class.

Comment: Im create api endpoint for login when user success login then I will respon user data info to the client

Comment: By adding custom response data you are breaking the rfc specification for oauth and you are not seperating the login process from the buisness logic side. I would NOT recommend this. This is bad practice imho

Comment: You should login first, get the token. Then do a second GET call to a ”/user” endpoint and present the user token and in turn return the user object to the client.

Comment: @Thomas Andolf, I think maby I need to follow you, really thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom content to the token using a [TokenEnhancer](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenEnhancer.html)

You can define it in your @Configuration class :

`endpoints.tokenEnhancer(yourTokenEnhancer)`

`yourTokenEnhancer` must be of a type implementing `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer` interface.

Anyway, note that this is a token enhancer, so you shouldn't use it as a user information provider.